# underscore .find() multiples with same key value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am currently trying to filter an object via POST from a form the form is made of checkboxes and as a result I need to be able to search an array of objects for multiple values on the same key.

My POST looks similar to this,

```
{
    tax_year: ['2016/17', '2017/18'],
    status : ['completed'],
    user : [1,4,78]
}
```

How would I go about search an array of objects and returning all the objects that have a matching key and value? I know I can do a single find with underscore like so,

```
var result = _.where(historyData, {tax_year: "2016/17"});
```

but I have no clue as to how to search for multiple matching keys and values?

Comment: [The `where` documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#where) has an example with multiple properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're matching on both of the values in an array value (regardless of whether there are more array values or not). If that's true, you might have to use the _.filter() method, where you can provide whatever logic you need in the 'predicate'. Alternatively, you could add a unique identifier on the server side to each record and match on that.